# After changing permalink, getting 404 for one particular category

Tags: htaccess, 404-error

For my webits seems fine:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress


# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php70” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php70 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Comment: It looks like you don't have `smileys` category but you have `smiley` category where `penguin` belongs to. Check `https://hdsmileys.com/smileys/penguin/`.

Comment: The category appears to be "smiley" (no "s"), not "smileys"? eg. `https://hdsmileys.com/smiley/penguin/` would appear to return a valid page.

Comment: Forgot to remove `s` from url in my previous comment. It should read `https://hdsmileys.com/smiley/penguin/`

Comment: I removed the s from the category- smileys and it worked fine . don't know what the issue smileys.